# Why Anylogic stopDelay() function throws error when Delay block is empty?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling, event-simulation

I have an event with action

`delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0));`

it works fine but when the delay block gets empty error shows up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGyJe.png)

Comment: Note that it is *not* `stopDelay` which throws the error. `stopDelay` takes the agent to stop the delay for; it is your attempt to get the first agent from an empty Delay block (`delay.get(0)`) that causes the error (and it should hopefully be intuitive that that would cause an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because your delay doesn't have any agent inside

so you need to do the following:

```
if(delay.size()>0){
   delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0)); 
}
```